# logrotate every 2 hours

Tags: ubuntu, logs, http, logrotate

I'm trying to make httpry logs every 2 hours. I added this to my `logrotate.conf` file:

```
/var/log/httpry/*.log {
    rotate 1
    weekly
    create 640 root admin
    missingok
    notifempty
}
```

I tried changing weekly to hourly (still need every 2 hours), but it doesn't work. I read to copy a script from cron.daily to cron.hourly but all my cron files are empty.

How can I create a new log file every 2 hours?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've seen this trick used before on a separate [blog](https://packetcloud.net/index.php/making-logrotate-rotate-apache-logs-every-hour-or-2-or-3/):

Create a config file for logrotate, let us call it `httpry.conf`

```
/var/log/httpry/*.log {
    size 2
    rotate 84
    compress
    missingok
    copytruncate
}
```

Then from cron (may need to be in root's crontab depending on the permissions and ownership of the log files), a crontab of:

```
0 */2 * * * logrotate -f /path/to/httpry.conf
```

**EDIT: to describe crontab editing for OP**

A crontab can be created for your user account by issuing `crontab -e`. If you want to edit a specific user's crontab, as root: `crontab -e user` or on some systems `crontab -e -u user`. You will then be put into an EDITOR which will allow you to edit the crontab, and wrting the file out will check the crontab for errors (giving an error if incorrect) or installing the crontab if correct.

The `rotate 84` option, as he describes in the blog, is to keep a weeks worth of logs. (24/2 hour intervals = 12 logs per day, 12 * 7 = 84 .. or 1 weeks worth of logs).

Comment: Can you explain the second part: `0 */2 * * * logrotate -f /etc/logrotate.d/apache`? I have never worked with cron before so it's a little confusing. I don't have an apache folder in `/etc/logrotate.d/` either.

Comment: Sorry that's a cut from my notes I took from the original blog, I will update to make clearer.

Comment: Just to clarify that crontab says "every two hours run the command `logrotate -f /path/to/httpry.conf`, more details can be found about crontab in the man pages `man 1 crontab` and `man 5 crontab`.

Comment: Sorry, computer won't boot up for some reason. Just to make sure, after I type crontab -e, I pasted the line 0 */2 **.... then saved it. I put httpry.conf in /etc/.

Comment: Never mind, I figured out why I couldn't boot. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: So long as the crontab line has `/etc/httpry.conf` at the end that should be fine.